# Sitecore settings for multilingual sites

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have been trying to know about multilingual site.

Where in url should be something like this when I switch between languages:

If language is

English: http://somesite.com/us/en/page.aspx

Danish: http://somesite.com/dk/da/page.aspx

Is there anyway that I can achieve this with sitecore setting without writing any code?

(reference: using sitecore 6.4)

Any help well appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the `linkManager` setting in the `web.config` you can turn language embedding on or off, however its of the form `en-US` or `en-GB` (**Note**: en-US is actually just `en`).

Set `languageEmbedding` to `always`:

```
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution :) forgot to answer myself for my question here. Anyways, Thanks Mark Ursino and i'm marking it as an answer